# Aliasing a name of a structure

Tags: c, struct

I have a structure that defines a timer, and I would like to have a generic name for the elements in the structure.  I want to create an alias so that I can use a generic name, such as TMR_IO, instead of T2CONbits.  This structure is attached to some control bits on a MCU, but I've had a really terrible time getting a redefinition.  The following is a small subset of the actual structure.

```
extern volatile unsigned int T2CON __attribute__((section("sfrs")));
typedef union {
  struct {
    unsigned w:32;
  };
} __T2CONbits_t;
extern volatile __T2CONbits_t T2CONbits __asm__ ("T2CON") __attribute__((section("sfrs")));
```

T2CONbits.w=0x12345678 is how I use this in the code, and I would really like a way to alias to this structure without explicitly using the the __T2CONbits_t assignment.  I would really like to have something where I could just make an alias of sorts to T2CONbits, so I can just use a generic name, such as TMR_IO.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you just looking for a macro like `#define TMR_IO T2CONbits.w`?

Comment: @Barmar  The issue is that there are different ICs, which a very similar code base.  For instance, on one IC, we have T5CONbits, and on another, it's T2CONbits, so I want to have something like a #define as you suggest but to address it as TMR_IO.w    All of those externs are causing GCC to be really picky and I'm not sure how to proceed. :/

Comment: @Barmar actually, your #define suggestion will work fine it seems.   I don't know what I did wrong before.  Write it up and I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a macro:

```
#define TMR_IO T2CONbits.w
```

Then you can write:

```
TMR_IO = 0x12345678;
```